# TortoiseSVN Icons not appearing after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-8.1

I am using `TortoiseSVN 1.8.7, 64 Bit`. As I upgraded to `Windows 8.1`, The `SVN Icons` are not seen.

I tried the `Clean Up` operation & also changing `Icon Overlays` to `Default` & `Shell`, still cannot see the Icons.

The SVN is working properly I can `Update` `Commit`.

How to get the `Icons` back?

Here is screen shot from `regedit` :-

[image]

Comment: What is the reason for Minus Points?

Comment: install 1.9.2 which adds spaces to the front of the registry entries to make sure that their are always loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to TortoiseSVN 1.9.2 or later: workaround for this problem added in [r26717](http://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/26717/)